# How to do statistics on Elasticsearch5.3 query request?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to do some statistics on ES query, such as find out the hottest words searched by customers last month.

How can I do that with ES, or should i use some other tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I don't know of a built in solution for this within elastic search, it sounds like something easy to do using elastic search. Every time you get a new query, you could save the search in a dedicated index, just make sure you store the searchText as a keyword (or enable fielddata):

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings":{
    "myFirstMapping": {
      "properties": {
        "searchText": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Whenever you want to get statistics, you can perform something like this:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "word": {
      "terms": {
        "field":"searchText",
        "size":10
      }
    }
  }
}
```